# Printing a whole number as a decimal in Javascript without rounding

Tags: javascript

I have a simple problem to solve, I have a variable containing a double, I'm reading in another double from user input. I need to sum the two numbers and print the result to the screen. In other languages I have worked in, just the fact that it was a double would result in it printing with a decimal, even if it is a whole number. In Javascript, this is not the case.

```
var d = 2.0;
console.log(d) // out is 2
```

I can force it to print a decimal by using `toFixed()`, but then it is going to round results of other input. If the result is 2.0, I want it to print "2.0" and if the result is 2.345, I want it to print "2.345".

The solution I have right now is to convert it to a string if it is a whole number:

```
var d2 = 4.0
console.log((d2 % 1 == 0) ? d2+".0" : d2) // out is 4.0
```

I feel like there must be some better way to do this. This seems very clunky to me. I've been searching for solutions, but everything I have found so far uses `toFixed()` or some other rounding.

Comment: JavaScript only has one type of number, so everything is a double. It doesn't care if it's a whole number; you have to do your formatting manually.

Comment: In JavaScript there is no such thing as decimal or double. Everything is a Number, which is rather confusing (and rather different than in most languages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a more Number-y solution could be:

```
var d = 4.0
var ds = Number.isInteger(d) ? d.toPrecision(2) : d.toString();
console.log(ds)
```

Comment: FYI - you'll need a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger#Polyfill) for `Number.isInteger` if you want  to support internet explorer -

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var d = 2.0;
var parsD = parseFloat(d);   //you have to parse d either as Float or Integer
console.log(parsD) // out will be in decimal without rounding up
```

You have to decide the number of decimals. Be realistic. e.g. for financial issues, 2 decimal places is just OK. In which case change line 2 to:

```
var parsD = parseFloat(d).toFixed(n)  //where n is an integer & number of decimals
```

This works fine.
In my case, I receive input on a form. The input can be integer or decimal. However when processing, every input is treated as decimal.

Answer (score 0):

For better dynamic printing (no useless leading zeroes) Use:

```
Number(num.toFixed(5)).toString()
```

Here an example to show the interpretation:

```
const num = 2.2;
console.log(
    Number(num.toFixed(5)).toString()
);
// 2.2

const num = 2.2;
console.log(
    num.toFixed(5)
);

// 2.20000
```

[Notice] You can use node interpreter to test faster and have a playground:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```js
function number(r){
const a= 4.43
const answer= a.tofixed(4)
console.log(answer)
return answer
}
```